# Ajax update dataTable from commandButton located in included file

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have such situation situation:
in file form.xhtml i have form used for filter some tables, i gave button "filter" defined here.

in file tableOne.xhtml, tableTwo.html, .. i have dataTable with id "filterTable", i've also included form.xhtml into this page. all pages with dataTables includes form.xhtml and all dataTables on them have the same id "filterTable"

what i want to do is to update dataTable[#filterTable] on  after filter button is pressed using ajax. button is created by <p:commandButton>. if form and datatable are defined in the same file, all i need is simply add update="filterTable" to my command bytton. but if i add it to button defined in form.xhtml i get "Cannot find component with identifier" error.

is it possible to dynamic update dataTables from outside xhtml files included on page? if it is, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

test.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="dtForm">
        <p:dataTable id="dataTable" />
    </h:form>
    <ui:include src="/include.xhtml" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

include.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="button" update=":dtForm" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```